# How can I use flag to change the mouse cursor to default or to other texture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first script that handle the mouse cursor :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HandleMouseCursor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool useDefaultCursor = true;
    public Texture2D mouse;
    public Texture2D hand;
    public Texture2D grab;
    public CursorMode cursorMode = CursorMode.Auto;
    public Vector2 hotSpot = Vector2.zero;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        if(useDefaultCursor == true)
        {
            mouse = Texture2D.def
        }

        setMouse();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    public void setMouse()
    {
        Cursor.SetCursor(mouse, hotSpot, cursorMode);
    }

    public void setHand()
    {
        Cursor.SetCursor(hand, hotSpot, cursorMode);
    }

    public void setGrab()
    {
        Cursor.SetCursor(grab, hotSpot, cursorMode);
    }
}
```

I added a flag : useDefaultCursor
and then tried to start using it :

```
if(useDefaultCursor == true)
            {
                mouse = Texture2D.def
            }
```

but not sure how to continue Texture2D don't have default property.

The second script use the first one methods :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UpdateCursor : MonoBehaviour
{
    HandleMouseCursor cursor;
    bool carrying;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        cursor = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<HandleMouseCursor>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (carrying)
            cursor.setGrab();
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        cursor.setHand();
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        cursor.setMouse();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        carrying = true;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        carrying = false;
        cursor.setMouse();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to use the flag useDefaultCursor if it's true use the regular default mouse cursor
if it's false use the mouse textures from the public fields if there are any textures assigned to the fields. if not textures assigned at all then use again the default mouse cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `HandleMouseCursor::setMouse()` just use the `useDefaultCursor` as you intended and write:

```
void setMouse()
{
    if (useDefaultCursor)
        Cursor.SetCursor(null, hotSpot, cursorMode);
    else
        Cursor.SetCursor(mouse, hotSpot, cursorMode);
}
```